# DIscord.py авторизация через токен пользователя

Tags: discord.py

При авторизации через токен бота код работает правильно, но как только токен заменяется на токен пользователя, событие on_message срабатывает только в случае, если данного пользователя упоминают. Можно ли как то читать все сообщения через пользователя?

Upd:
Способ сделать чтение через метод on_message я не нашел, вместо этого я использовал channel.history и каждый раз проверял, нету ли новых сообщений, но это все еще не является ответом на вопрос

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, данные действия помогут вам решить вашу проблему: в аккаунте пользователя можно вручную включить упоминания при любом сообщении. Для этого нужно нажать правой кнопкой мыши по серверу/каналу, затем выбрать пункт уведомления и параметрах уведомлений выбрать пункт все сообщения.